# Angular - change classes of all elements of an *ngFor except for the one clicked

Tags: css, angular, typescript

i'm using angular 10 and i want to create an interface where when you click on an element (of an array[???]), the others collapse (in this easier version change color and width).

Then if you click on another one this go back to normal and all the others collapse and if you click again on the second one all comes back to normal.

Images on bottom.

I was able only to do the opposite of the 1st part: if you click on an element, this one change.

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let name of disney" class="basic" (click)="function(name)" [class.selected]="clickedClass === name">
    {{name}}
</div>
```

Ts:

```
disney: string[] = ['pippo', 'pluto', 'topolino'];

clickedClass: any;
  function(name) {
    this.clickedClass = name;
  }
```

Css:

```
.basic {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: beige;
}

.selected {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: burlywood;
}
```

3 images for let u understand what i means:

[If you, hypothetically, click on the last paragraph of the 1st image the others collapse as the 2nd image show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVM8e.png)

[All except the one clicked collapsed and if you click on the middle paragraph you'll obtain the 3rd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwxj8.png)

[If you click on the opened paragraph you'll go to the 1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Zob.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

html:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 30px;" *ngFor="let name of disney" (click)="function(name)"
    [class.basic]="basicClass == 'basic' || [basicClass == '' && collapsedClass == ''] "
    [class.selected]="selectedClass === name"
    [class.collapsed]="collapsedClass == 'collapsed' && selectedClass !== name">
    {{name}}
</div>
```

css:

```
.basic {
    height          : 100px;
    background-color: beige;
}

.selected {
    height          : 100px;
    background-color: rgb(135, 207, 147);
}

.collapsed {
    height          : 50px;
    background-color: rgb(158, 185, 235);
}
```

ts:

```
disney: string[] = ['pippo', 'pluto', 'topolino'];

  selectedClass: string;
  collapsedClass: string;
  basicClass: string;

  function(name) {
    if (this.selectedClass === name) {
      console.log(name);
      this.basicClass = "basic";
      this.selectedClass = '';
      this.collapsedClass = '';
    }
    else {
      this.selectedClass = name;
      this.collapsedClass = "collapsed";
      this.basicClass = '';
    }
  }
```